Outputting from query with multiple GROUP BY conditions
I have a simple query with a GROUP BY clause that works great. But I want to expand that to a GROUP BY on 2 columns and unsure how to output the way I would like. Most examples show output as a table and I am trying to output the CNT with text on a page.
This brings back the number of live shows for a band but under 5 different band names.
The existing query is:
SELECT COUNT(m.muID) AS shwCnt, m.bandID, b.\* FROM musicTbl m, bandTbl b WHERE m.bandID = b.bandID GROUP BY m.bandID

and the existing output is:
while ($rowS = mysqli_fetch_array($resultS)) {
$fnt = array('<span class="ln">', '</span>');
$stripped = str_replace($fnt, '', $rowS['bandName']);
echo '<div class="pic5">
<div class="pic5Box"><p><a class="regLnk" href="' . $rowS['bandPage'] . '.php"><img alt="' . $stripped . ' plays ' . $rowS['bandMusic'] . '" src="pics/' . $rowS['bandIcon'] . '" /><br /><span class="lge">' . $stripped . '</span></a><br />(<span class="prpl">' . $rowS['bandMusic'] . '</span>)<br>' . $rowS['shwCnt'] . ' ';
if ($rowS['shwCnt'] == "1") {
    echo 'show';
} else {
    echo 'shows';
}
echo '</p></div>
</div>';
}

The output is at https:canadianbeauty.org/music.php.
What I want to do is add a second field to the grouping for if the entry is an album rather than a live show adding the field m.muAlbum as "GROUP BY m.bandID, m.muAlbum".
In the example linked above under Two Bobs and A Mule it states 9 shows and with the additional grouping it should say 8 shows & 1 album. I am confusing myself as to how the while() output should be coded to show the 2 different numbers.
Haven't really been able to get my head around this.
